# What are the possible security threats that any web application may face?

Tags: web, security

I have made a web app using backbone.js. I'm now trying to cover the security aspects of it?

What are the potential security threats that any web app may face and steps one need to take to secure the app from those threats ?

Answer (score 1):

As its a JS app its probably worth taking a quick look at the owasp top 10 in relation to JS

http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=125

```
A1 - Injection
A2 - Cross Site Scripting (XSS)
A3 - Broken Authentication and Session Management
A4 - Insecure Direct Object References
A5 - Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF)
A6 - Security Misconfiguration
A7 - Insecure Cryptographic Storage
A8 - Failure to Restrict URL Access
A9 - Insufficient Transport Layer Protection
A10 - Unvalidated Redirects and Forwards
```

You don't really give any details on what the site does or storage but the list above (with more detail within the link) is the best place to start.

Ideally you should think about the security after defining each feature.